# Returning the closest time to the current time from results in the database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$host = "**************t.com"; //replace with database hostname 
$username = "**********"; //replace with database username 
$password = "**********"; //replace with database password 
$db_name = "a8463280_trans"; //replace with database name

$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');


   $time_now = date('H:i');
   echo($time_now);
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT departure_time FROM stop_times WHERE departure_time > '$time_now'") or die(mysql_error());
   $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 
   $result = mysql_query($sql);      
   echo($data);
```

?>

The time data in my database is in the format 00:00:00. When I run the code above I get returned "19:57Array" I am trying to return a the time that is closest to the current time.
Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're using the creaky old `mysql_query` interface instead of something more modern? Don't forget to format your time using the same formatting string.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply i solved to problem now. I am not using mysql_query anymore. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! One less legacy application out there.

Answer (score 0):

you try use array ($data) as string, try:

```
echo $data['departure_time'];
```

you should also consider use more secure db driver ie. mysqli.